# ModuleNotFoundError when executing but IntelliJ shows no errors

Tags: python, intellij-idea, robotframework

[image]

I have 2 folders containing python files like above. I've already marked them as **Source Root** on IntelliJ so that I can import modules normally between them

Today, I tried to import the module `common_element` into `common_utils` using:

```
import common_element
```

And the IDEA is just fine, now errors happen. I can browse between 2 modules normally. But when I executing it, it thrown "ModuleNotFoundError" like below:
[image]

I don't know the reason why, every file in `common_ui` can import files from`common_utils` & run the project without errors, but NOT vice versa

What should I do now? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH" checkbox enabled in your run/debug configuration? If this doesn't help, it would be great if you could share a minimal project to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an empty `__init__.py` file inside the `common_ui` directory to make python treat this directory as a python module.

Comment: But the problem is that: every file in `common_ui` can import files from `common_utils` & run the project without errors, but NOT vice versa. Do you know why?

Comment: After adding the `__init__.py` file to `common_ui`, Import `comment_element` like this: `from common_ui import common_element`

Comment: It does not work man. the IDEA still show red underlined errors

Answer (score 0):

If want to do it without adding `__init__.py` and creating packages, you can do this:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..'))
import common_ui.common_element
```

Comment: I just rechecked. Every file in `common_ui` can import files from `common_utils` & run the project without errors, but NOT vice versa. Do you know why?

Comment: Try printing sys.path and sys.modules in both the folders and compare the result.